# MSVC++ map<int, list<unique_ptr<test>>> does not compile referencing deleted function

Tags: visual-c++, c++11, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <list>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct test {
    test(const test&) = delete;
    test& operator = (const test&) = delete;
    test() = default;
    ~test() = default;
};

typedef unique_ptr<test> test_ptr;

int main() {
    list<test_ptr> test_ptr_list;   //This is line 17, where the error occurs
    // comment out next line and it compiles on VC++.
    map<int, list<test_ptr>> test_ptr_map; //error occurs if this is not commented
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles in [`ideone C++11`](http://ideone.com/WOw37k) but fails in `MSVC++ 2013 CTP Nov 2013`. I'm quite certain this should compile as the `unique_ptr` can move even if my wrapped object cannot copy. Works OK with `list`, not with `map`.

**Is this a `MSVC++` bug or am I doing something wrong?**

The error message is:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(600): error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=test
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\memory(1486) : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=test
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(723) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Other>::construct<_Objty,const std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<_Ty>>&>(_Objty *,const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Other=std::_List_node<std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>,void *>
1>  ,            _Objty=std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>
1>  ,            _Ty=test
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(723) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Other>::construct<_Objty,const std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<_Ty>>&>(_Objty *,const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Other=std::_List_node<std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>,void *>
1>  ,            _Objty=std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>
1>  ,            _Ty=test
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(872) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,const std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>&>(std::allocator<_Other> &,_Objty *,const std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_List_node<std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>,void *>>
1>  ,            _Ty=std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>
1>  ,            _Other=std::_List_node<std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>,void *>
1>  ,            _Objty=std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(872) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,const std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>&>(std::allocator<_Other> &,_Objty *,const std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_List_node<std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>,void *>>
1>  ,            _Ty=std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>
1>  ,            _Other=std::_List_node<std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>,void *>
1>  ,            _Objty=std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\list(835) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<_Other>>::construct<_Ty,const std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>&>(_Ty *,const std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Other=std::_List_node<std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>,void *>
1>  ,            _Ty=std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\list(835) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<_Other>>::construct<_Ty,const std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>&>(_Ty *,const std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Other=std::_List_node<std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>,void *>
1>  ,            _Ty=std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\list(1062) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_List_node<std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,void *> *std::_List_buy<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,_Alloc>::_Buynode<const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>&>(std::_List_node<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,void *> *,std::_List_node<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,void *> *,const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=test
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<test_ptr>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\list(1062) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_List_node<std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,void *> *std::_List_buy<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,_Alloc>::_Buynode<const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>&>(std::_List_node<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,void *> *,std::_List_node<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,void *> *,const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=test
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<test_ptr>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\list(1424) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::list<test_ptr,std::allocator<_Ty>>::_Insert<const std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>&>(std::_List_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>,std::_Iterator_base0>,const std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=test_ptr
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\list(1424) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::list<test_ptr,std::allocator<_Ty>>::_Insert<const std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>&>(std::_List_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>,std::_Iterator_base0>,const std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=test_ptr
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\list(1384) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::list<test_ptr,std::allocator<_Ty>>::_Insert_range<_Iter>(std::_List_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>,std::_Iterator_base0>,_Iter,_Iter,std::forward_iterator_tag)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=test_ptr
1>  ,            _Iter=std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>>>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\list(1384) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::list<test_ptr,std::allocator<_Ty>>::_Insert_range<_Iter>(std::_List_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>,std::_Iterator_base0>,_Iter,_Iter,std::forward_iterator_tag)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=test_ptr
1>  ,            _Iter=std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>>>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\list(924) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>> std::list<test_ptr,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>::insert<std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>>>(std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>>,_Iter,_Iter)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=test
1>  ,            _Iter=std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>>>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\list(924) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>> std::list<test_ptr,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>::insert<std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>>>(std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>>,_Iter,_Iter)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=test
1>  ,            _Iter=std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<std::unique_ptr<test,std::default_delete<test>>>>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\list(917) : while compiling class template member function 'std::list<test_ptr,std::allocator<_Ty>>::list(const std::list<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=test_ptr
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xstring(1123) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::list<test_ptr,std::allocator<_Ty>>::list(const std::list<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=test_ptr
1>          ]
1>          c:\code\test\test\main.cpp(17) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::list<test_ptr,std::allocator<_Ty>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=test_ptr
1>          ]
```

> **PS**: Posted this on [`CONNECT`](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/960021) with an easier method to reproduce it
> **`std::pair<int, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>> int_pair;`**.

**PPS**: *The bug is fixed and the fix will be included in **VS14 RTM***.

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: @TimoGeusch `Referencing deleted function.` Basically, the `pair<int, list<unique_ptr>>` inside the `map` does not move but tries to copy the `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Works fine with VC++ 18.00.21005.1 and VC++ 19.00.21928.  Also with my VC++2013... but indeed fails with VC++ Nov 2013 CTP.  I posted the full error message.

Comment: Basically, MSVC's map seems to require that the value type is copiable (in the Nov 2013 CTP).  Fascinating.  I'd have to check the spec, but I think that's a bug.

Comment: Actually... the compiler message is calling out `std::basic_string::assign(const std::basic_string&)` as the thing requiring the list to be copiable.  That' _can't_ be right.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes. `VC++` is fascinating is so many ways. Especially when you find a bug... and start to workaround it. :)

Comment: @CodeAngry: Did you notice that the compiler error occurs on the line `test_ptr_list` _before_ the `map`?

Comment: Actually, when I comment out the `test_ptr_list`, the error message changes and is slightly more sane.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0c7b95ea8cfd420  However, it's still claiming that `std::list<test_ptr>` can't be instantiated because the copy constructor can't be instantiated, which is dead wrong.  The fact that it still blames `std::basic_string::assign` doesn't help.

Comment: @MooingDuck Will do. I already tweeted the VC++ team the link to this question.

Comment: @CodeAngry: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback, and post a link here for us

Comment: @MooingDuck Posted it. Added a link in the `Question`. First time I use `Connect`. Still not sure why there's nothing more `C++` specific in those categories... It's all .NET and no C++. I have no idea if I categorized it properly.

Comment: For those who have not clicked on the Connect link: this issue has been fixed and should be available in VS 14 RTM.

Answer (score 0):

The MSVC bug is fixed and the fix will be included in VS14 RTM: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/960021